# Unity: How to access to text mesh via script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**Unity: How to access to text mesh via script**
[image]

I want to set the value of the text mesh.

```
public Text textMeshObject; // Here is my text mesh object. Text is the class of text mesh?
public void Update(){
    if(___some_condition___){
        textMeshObject.text = "abc";
    }
}
```

Comment: Well .. like this ^^ What exactly is the issue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You get the reference to the TextMesh component by using GetComponent:

```
private TextMesh textMeshObject;

private void Start()
{
    textMeshObject = GetComponent<TextMesh>(); 
}

public void Update()
{
    if (___some_condition___)
    {
        textMeshObject.text = "abc";
    }
}
```